# Find Websites based on the Fonts they use

Tags: html, css, web-scraping, search, fonts

I'm working on a research project where I want to analyse content produced by the anthroposophic movement (you might know them from steiner/waldorf schools, especially if you live in a germanophone country).

I'm especially interested in content of movement supporters who are not attached to any official associations of the movement.
In order to identify websites/blogs by these actors, I came up with the idea to identify them based on the usage of a particular font, that is regularly used in the movement. The Antropos font (https://www.dafont.com/de/antropos.font) is designed in line with the rules of aesthetics the founder of the movement came up with. It is seldomly used by actors unrelated to the movement.

Is there a way to search the web based on the fonts a website uses? I had a look at googles advanced search operators but that did not yield any result. Since fonts are part of the css, the general question is whether there is a way to find websites that use a specified css element.

Comment: use this chrome extension for seeing what font a website use. it is called "WhatFont" (is not only this one, but there are a lot more similar if you want just search on google)

Comment: if you need a custom code for searching with that filtres you can use Google API https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview#prerequisites, just see the documentation (also to mention their API is not cheap 5$ for 1000querys, the first 100 are free with your API key) if you need a lot of queries then search online some alternative. this API is helpful only for having the list of websites, not getting the font, you need some script that gets the font from that website, then display it to the user.  (here is their landing page: https://programmablesearchengine.google.com/about/)